# Expression of one's "emotions", "feelings" or "sentiments"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference, expressions

Please imagine a couple who love each other too much. The man goes abroad for a military mission for two years. During this period of time they are connecting to each other via a phone call every other two or three months and sometimes drop some lines to each other [reminds me of the movie Pearl Harbor.] 
The mission gets over and the army comes back home! Lots of wives are waiting for their husbands! The plane containing the soldiers lands. Most of the women are happy. But the wife of the soldier in my question cries all the time. She cannont wait to see her husband.
When they meet, they embrace and kneel against each other and look at each other tearfully....

What they were doing:

> 1) They were **expressing their emotions**. 
>   2) They were **expressing their feelings**. 
>   3) They were **expressing their sentiments**.

Based on dictionary definitions, #1 and #2 work to me, but I have no reason to reject #3.

I wonder if you could let me know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sentiment** - a thought, opinion, or idea based on a feeling about a situation, or a way of thinking about something

**Feeling** -  emotions, especially those influenced by other people

**emotion** - a strong feeling such as love or anger, or strong feelings in general

I.e. Feeling and Emotion are almost entirely synonymous, emotion just tends to imply a stronger feeling. [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/emotion)

Whereas sentiment is a thought, not necessarily rooted in feeling, (as @Lorel suggested this tends to imply a more analytical notion). [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sentiment)